# XLST Lookup Table returns false

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, lookup-tables

I'm new to XSLT, but I have looked into this and I can't seem to get this working. I've got an xsl document and an external xml document. I'm importing the document as a variable $LOOKUP

**External XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<labels>
    <label ead="physloc">Physical Location</label>
    <label ead="unittitle">Title</label>
</labels>
```

**VARIABLE**

`<xsl:variable name="LOOKUP" select="document('includes/labels.xml', /)" />`

**XSL**

```
<xsl:value-of select="$LOOKUP/labels/label[@ead='unittitle']" />
```

When I'm debugging this (oXygen with Saxon EE 9.5.1.7) I can see that the document has been imported, and I can even browse the Node/Value set with the debugger, but I get nothing printed out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Perhaps your stylesheet uses `xpath-default-namespace` and that way the path does not work. Try `<xsl:value-of xpath-default-namespace="" select="$LOOKUP/labels/label[@ead='unittitle']" />`. If that does not help then show us minimal but complete samples allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That was the answer.  Thank you very much. I've been pulling my hair out on that one.

Comment: OK, I have put my suggestion into an answer so that you can accept it and the question is marked as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your stylesheet uses `xpath-default-namespace` and that way the path does not work. Try `<xsl:value-of xpath-default-namespace="" select="$LOOKUP/labels/label[@ead='unittitle']" />`.